# Patch MediaWiki, skip minor version?

Tags: mediawiki, patch

I want to patch MediaWiki from 1.23.1 to latest 1.23.4 (on Ubuntu 12.04.5) I plan to use patch: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading#Using_patch

My questions is can I directly apply Patch 1.23.**4** or need first got 1.23.**2**, 1.23.**3**?

Based on file size it looks like I can't jump version  (4 is smaller than 3)
https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki//1.23/

```
mediawiki-1.23.2.patch.gz   30-Jul-2014 19:34   4.0K     
mediawiki-1.23.3.patch.gz   27-Aug-2014 21:49   21K  
mediawiki-1.23.4.patch.gz   24-Sep-2014 20:12   7.9K
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: the patches are incremental, so if you choose that upgrade route, you'll need to apply each of them in sequence.

You can confirm this by looking at the patch files themselves.  For example, the [1.23.4 patch](http://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.23/mediawiki-1.23.4.patch.gz) starts with the following lines:

```
diff -Nruw -x messages -x '*.png' -x '*.jpg' -x '*.xcf' -x '*.gif' -x '*.svg' -x '*.tiff' -x '*.zip' -x '*.xmp' -x '.git*' mediawiki-1.23.3/includes/config/GlobalVarConfig.php mediawiki-1.23.4/includes/config/GlobalVarConfig.php
--- mediawiki-1.23.3/includes/config/GlobalVarConfig.php        2014-09-24 19:58:09.941581474 +0000
+++ mediawiki-1.23.4/includes/config/GlobalVarConfig.php        2014-09-24 19:55:15.782579699 +0000
```

From this header (which is in [unified diff format](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Unified_format)) you can tell that the patch is against MediaWiki 1.23.3, i.e. it assumes that you've already applied the earlier patches.

If you tried to apply the latest patch without first applying the earlier ones, at least parts of it would almost certainly fail to apply cleanly.  Some parts, however, might succeed, leaving you with a weird hybrid version of MediaWiki that would include some of the fixes from the latest minor version, but none from the earlier ones you skipped (and which would probably still retain its original version number).  To avoid such a confusing situation, it may be a good idea to use the `--dry-run` option to the [`patch`](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_%28Unix%29) utility to make sure that each patch will apply cleanly before you actually apply it.

Comment: thx, I updated https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading#Using_patch with this info.